# select2_from_ajax_multiple optimize query for laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-backpack

I have 2 tables:

```
1. Users
2. Tags
```

> tags_users is the *Pivot table*

These tables have a many-to-many relation.

**Why does `addField` in my `UserCrudController` make excessive queries when the result is accessible from a single query?**

Example:

When I edit a user having multiple tags, `addField` makes the following queries:

```
select * from `tags` where `tags`.`id` = '11' limit 1;
select * from `tags` where `tags`.`id` = '13' limit 1;
select * from `tags` where `tags`.`id` = '14' limit 1;
select * from `tags` where `tags`.`id` = '57' limit 1;
```

I understand that `select2_from_ajax` needs to make an AJAX request every time I retrieve new information, but how about just getting the first selected result from the User object?

Like this: `User::find(1)->tags`. This returns the tags collection for the user and avoids multiple queries to get same result.

This is my UserCrudController:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/023c2eb5749180967efe0a24dbb7125d95815537

Its the part of code:

```
$this->crud->addField([ // Select2Multiple = n-n relationship (with pivot table)
        'label' => 'Tags',
        'type' => 'select2_from_ajax_multiple_custom',
        'name' => 'tags', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'entity' => 'tags', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model' => Tag::class, // foreign key model
        'data_source' => route("search.tags"),
        'placeholder' => "Select a city",
        'minimum_input_length' => 2, // minimum characters to type before querying results
        'pivot' => true, // on create&update, do you need to add/delete pivot table entries?
]);
```

Comment: I am not sure what are you meaning by saying "select2_from_ajax", I don't know if it is a JS library or something I didn't know about Laravel... What I can say is that, maybe you need to do [Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and you will only do 1 query.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include controller code where `addField` is called? If you don't mind, also share a screenshot of your rendered template.

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that just how select2's AJAX functionality works. Every time they submit an AJAX call, they send all the data it has collected. Not just what has been added. As such, if you have multiple entries selected already, an SQL call will be made for each of them...